# Magento 2 Import: "Check Data" and "Import" Button. What php method is called?

Tags: magento2, import

I have two similar questions regarding the import in Magento 2:

1. what class method is called when the `Check Data` button is clicked?

The button has this attribute `onclick="varienImport.postToFrame();"`, but I am not able to figrure out what php file is called ultimatley.

2. What class method is called when the subsequent `Import` button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Ajax validation will be called: `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Validate.php`

2) `vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Start.php`

> What class method is called when the subsequent "Import" button is
>   clicked?

Comment: I have created a custom import functionality, while check date everything is fine, but when i hit the import button nothing is happening(loading the symbol). i also checked the import button action, it's going to import/start function. kindly share your thoughts